# Ava/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file /usr/lib/attica_kde.so

Tags: ubuntu, scala

Пытаюсь запустить `Scala` под `Ubuntu 12.10`, вызываю в командной строке `scala`
и получаю ошибку:

> java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file /usr/lib/attica_kde.so
>   Это можно как-нибудь исправить?

У меня не KDE стоит, а Unity. Но ведь по идее утилитам командной строки должно быть без разницы.

**Update:**

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
```

**Update 2:**

```
myname@mycomp:~$ scala -version
```

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file
>   /usr/lib/attica_kde.so

То есть я не пытаюсь запустить какую-либо программу, я хочу запустить scala хотя бы саму по себе, для начала.

Comment: А как вы ставили скалу? Через apt-get? обычные java приложения работают?

Comment: Scala - просто скачал с официального сайта, разархивировал, положил в /usr/share. То есть без apt-get. Обычные Java-приложения - работают (пробовал единственное приложение).

Comment: А как вы её запускаете? Какой командой?

Comment: Просто "scala".

Comment: environment variables настраивали ?

Comment: Не настраивал.

Comment: тогда вам нужно в .profile записать что то типа 

export SCALA_HOME=$HOME/scala-2.10.3 

и прилепить потом что то типа $PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin для переменной path

вот тут человек описал http://j2stock.blogspot.ru/2013/09/scala-ubuntu.html

Comment: Установил переменные тем способом, что описан в статье и пересказан вами здесь. Не помогло.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file /usr/lib/attica_kde.so

Comment: @dmitry_iii я предполагаю 2 вещи: 

а) вы не так настроили переменные окружения

б) у вас установлена java < 1.5

Comment: мне тут мой котяра подсказывает, что у вас в classpath не прописана scala. Пересоберите свой jar-ник, либо добавьте.

scala -version что выдает ?

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что надо было не скачивать сам архив Scala с её сайта, а ставить пакет "scala" через apt-get. Тогда она работает нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Scala которая находится в пакетах системы и ставиться через apt-get обычно является достаточно старой. К тому же достаточно часто требуется наличие нескольких разных версий (некоторые версии scala не являются бинарно совместимыми). Для того чтобы с легкостью установить последнюю версию Scala, groovy а так же других jvm языков, средств сборки, а так же управлять различными версиями существует иструмент [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/). Он позволяет устанавливать софт с легкостью пакетного менеджера. Установить sdkman, и запустите новую версию терминала, после этого вы можете спокойно установить последнюю версию scala.

Чтобы узнать список доступного для установки ПО воспользуйтесь коммандой `sdk list` (для выхода используйте q). Для установки Scala воспользуйтесь следующей командой `sdk install scala`, после чего будет установлена последняя версия. Установка sbt выполняется аналогично.